# Spring boot JPA - Query Many to Many with extra column

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using Spring Boot for backend in my project. In the database (MySQL) I have a many-to-many relationship. The entities are:

- **Interest** with fields id, nameInterest and priority
- **User** with fields id, email, age, genre, userName, password and priority.
- **RelUserInterest** (table intermediate) with fields user, interest and priority.

*Interest entity*

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(unique = true)
private String nameInterest;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "interest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotNull
Set<RelUserInterest> priority = new HashSet<>();
```

*User entity*

```
@Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

@NotNull
@Column (unique = true) private String email;

@NotNull private int age;
@NotNull private String genre;
@NotNull private String userName;
@NotNull private String password;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotNull
Set<RelUserInterest> priority = new HashSet<>();
```

*RelUserInterest entity*

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
User user;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "interest_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Interest interest;

int priority;
```

### What I want

I want a query that return the next information: the list of interest by user with the extra column (in this case **priority** column). In format JSON would be:

```
[
 {
   interest_id: 1,
   name_interest: "Museum",
   priority: 5
 },
 {
   interest_id: 2,
   name_interest: "Cathedral",
   priority: 6
 }
]
```

### What I have tried

**Method findBy**

I have tried this method in the repository:

```
public interface InterestRepository extends CrudRepository<Interest, Long> {
     ....
     List<Interest> findByPriority_user(User user);
}
```

But return an array with the name_interest and the interest_id

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same question as you but no answer.
I have a bridge table and extra column called active.
I want to query the data result where active = 1 in the bridge table but never works...
looking for answer here!

Comment: did you find an answer?